# How to customize button in UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone

I have implementing listing page in UITableView.Now i am flicking finger on to the table cell then delete button appear but i want to my custom image insted of delete.Is it possible please   give me advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your own button and add it to your cell as a subView.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in way to change that button, it's part of the standard UI.  You could, however, catch the flick yourself, and create your own button that says whatever you want.

I think it might be possible to grab the deleteButton reference and alter it, but that would affect the whole application and isn't a good practice to get into.